# Извлечение данных из XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlparser

```
1) Сделать синтаксический разбор XML файла (parser).
2) Спроектировать и создать свою структутру хранения содержимого XML файла. Важно: Каждый элемент должен знать позиции своего начала и окончания в файле.
3) Заполнить структуру, созданную в п.2 парсером созданным в п.1.
4) Показать заполненную структуру на экране. GUI должно включать:
   4.1. Дерево с тегами и комментариями.
        В тегах нужно вывести имя, значение, позиций начала и окончания тега в файле, а также позиций начала и окончания в файле имени и значения тега.
        В комментариях нужно вывести собственно сам комментарий, позиции начала и окончания в файле.
   4.2. Таблицу, которая при выборе тега отображает аттрибуты, их значения, позиции начала и окончания в файле (как имени аттрибута, так и его значения).
```

Собственно мне нужно выполнить это задание, но я битый час сижу читаю и пытаюсь хоть что то понять. Можете мне объяснить, что значит "спроектировать свою структуру хранения" ? Допустим, у меня есть автоматически созданный xml документ:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cardpack>
  <card id="cardId" name="Фродо" type="Хоббит">
    <attack>10</attack>
    <health>120</health>
    <mana>30</mana>
    <description>Хоббит бродит по траве. Хоббит бродит по лесам. Хоббит любит прелести.</description>
  </card>
  <card id="cardId" name="Hgff" type="Хоббит">
    <attack>10</attack>
    <health>120</health>
    <mana>30</mana>
    <description>Хоббит бродит по траве. Хоббит бродит по лесам. Хоббит любит прелести.</description>
  </card>
</cardpack>
```

можно ли сказать, что это моя собственная структура хранения ?
В пункте 4 и во всех его подпунктах, я вообще ничего не понял. Что значит позиция начала и конца тега ? (имелось в виду открывающий и закрывающий тег ?) После прочитанного я просто не представляю чем мне воспользоваться чтобы выполнить задание. Бросил взгляд на XPath, но все равно сомневаюсь что я хоть что то понял. Объясните мне пожалуйста, если не сложно, что тут вообще нужно сделать ?

Comment: Хм, ну и задание. Смотрите. Структура хранения имеет смысл только тогда, когда определены нужные операции. Условие наподобие «элемент должен знать позицию в файле» вообще лишено смысла, т. к. говорит «как», а не «для чего». Выясните у преподавателя, **какие операции должны поддерживаться**.

Ещё один парсер XML писать поучительно, но скучно.

Comment: Если лишь только получение позиции начала/конца, вас устроит такая структура:

    class XmlNode
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<XmlAttribute> Attributes { get; }

        public int startCharacterNumberInSomeTextRepresentation { get; set; }
        public int endCharacterNumberInSomeTextRepresentation { get; set; }
    }

    class XmlAttribute
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Заметьте, что позиция начала и окончания не имеет в принципе никакого смысла, так как XML можно записать в текстовый файл миллионом различных способов (namespace'ы, комментарии, игнорируемые пробелы), и позиции элементов будут отличаться.

Comment: @VladD, самое смешное, так это то, что это задание дали на собеседовании, а не на учебе. Спасибо за ответ. Многое прояснили для меня.

Comment: *Интересное задание* для собесседования (это где же так серьезно подходят к кандидатам? (правда интересно)).

--

Как-то я писал похожую штуку (правда на Си и позиции в памяти а не файле). 

Получилось строк 100 в .h и больше 500 в .c (и наверное несколько недель писал и отлаживал).

Вот [тут](http://zametkinapolyah.ru/kak-sozdavat-html-shablony-sajtov/zametki-o-xml-i-xlst/razmetka-xml-dokumenta-xml-atributy-koren-xml-dokumenta-deklaracii-v-xml-kommentarii-v-xml-sintaksis-xml-dokumenta.html) и [тут](http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm) нашел внятное описание XML.

(может и Вам пригодится).

Comment: @avp, [вот ссылка на саму компанию](http://spb.hh.ru/employer/1481869). Спасибо за предоставленные ссылки.